# Amazon Linux pecl_http installed but not providing functions

Tags: php, pecl, amazon-ami

I've installed PHP's `pecl_http` extension using the Amazon Linux `php54-pecl-http` Yum package.

- `php -i` shows the `http.ini` file loaded
- `http.ini` has the `extension=http.so` line in it
- `php -m` shows the HTTP module as installed
- `pecl list` shows `pecl_http 2.0.0beta1` as installed.

However, when I attempt to use any of its functions - `new HttpRequest()`, `http_build_url()`, etc. - they come back as nonexistent. I am running everything on the CLI (this is a utility server) so no chance of disparate `php.ini` files between environments.

`php -i`'s http block states:

```
http

HTTP Support => enabled
Extension Version => 2.0.0beta1

Used Library => Compiled => Linked
libz => 1.2.5 => 1.2.5
libcurl => 7.24.0 => 7.24.0
libevent => 1.4 or greater => 2.0.18-stable
libserf => disabled => disabled

                            Persistent Handles                            
Provider => Ident => Used => Free
http_client.curl => N/A => 0 => 0
http_client_pool.curl => N/A => 0 => 0
http_client_datashare.curl => N/A => 0 => 0

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
http.etag.mode => crc32b => crc32b
http.persistent_handle.limit => -1 => -1
```

Has anyone experienced this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a little late, but perhaps this helps someone else landing here...

Insure that you are referencing the correct version of the pecl_http API.  They moved to namespaces in v2, so the calling convention is quite different.  Much of the documentation around on the web references methods in v1.

http://devel-m6w6.rhcloud.com/mdref/http

Answer (score 1):

Please try

`strace -fF -o /tmp/wtf php your_php_script.php`

And then comb through `/tmp/wtf` file with a text editor/viewer/grep variant of your choice to see 1) proper php.ini was read and 2) if http.so extension was actually loaded.